# How to select the second visible row after applying a filter

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

To select the first row of filtered data I use the following:

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 3).Select
```

I thought to select the second row of filtered data I would change the 1 in `Cells(1, 3)` to a 2:

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(2, 3).Select
```

However, this takes me to a cell that is hidden from the filter.

How do I select the second row of filtered data?

Comment: If a range has multiple Areas, you can't reliably index into it using Cells: for example if the first Area has only one row, Cells(2, 3) is the third cell in the row below that, even though that cell isn't in your range.   You'll need to loop over the areas to find the second visible row.

Comment: Hi Tim, can you post some code showing how you would loop over the areas to find the second visible row please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Sub SelectVisibleRowByIndex()
    Dim lastRow As Long, visibleCount As Long, i As Long, rowIndex As Long
    
    'Set the index of the row you want to select, you can select the 2nd, 3rd, etc.
    rowIndex = 2
    
    ' Get the last row in the sheet
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    
    ' Loop through each row and count the visible rows
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Not Rows(i).Hidden Then
            visibleCount = visibleCount + 1
            If visibleCount = rowIndex Then
                ' Once we find the row with the specified index, select the entire row
                Rows(i).Select
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```